# angular 2 html video non english subtitles served by apache2

Tags: apache, angular

I have angular 2 app with latest angular-cli. App has html video player and is able to play videos with english subtitles (vtt). Video and subtitle files are served with apache2 and so is angular bundle from dist/. English subtitles are working fine but non english simply not appear in the video.

The key difference is when I access non-en sub. with chrome a get the encoding right (expected chars.). But when accessed (loaded by track tag) encoding is wrong (some messy chars.).

I only noticed difference in req header: accept, but I doubt that's the cause.

**direct access with chrome:**
[image: direct access with chrome]
[image: direct access with chrome: vtt]

**loaded by track:**
[image: loaded by track]
[image: loaded by track: vtt]

I'm including my apache configs (last lines are just tries with encoding, long time no see apache...).

**apache2.conf:**

```
...
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
 AddType application/x-javascript .js
 AddType text/css .css
 AddType text/plain .webapp
 AddType text/xml .xml
 AddType application/xml .xml
 AddType application/javascript .js
 AddType application/javascript .json
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
 <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:rar|zip)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpg|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:avi|mov|mp4)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.mp3$ no-gzip dont-vary
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
<FilesMatch \.vtt$>
 ForceType text/vtt;charset=utf-8
</FilesMatch>
AddType text/vtt .vtt
AddCharset UTF-8 .vtt
```

**apache2 conf sites-enabled/000-default.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/hvp/>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Redirect permanent / https://myserver/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver/privkey.pem

    <Directory /var/www/hvp/>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/https_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/https_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**What could cause this behaviour? thx.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

First, when a file has a .vtt suffix chrome interprets it and finds right encoding. So comparing these two was pointless. Now when subs are working and I look in network tab I see messy chars anyway, but in player it's working.

Second, replacing commas with dots in time definition helped alongside with editing in webstorm and checking result in vlc.

So the real problem were the subtitle file's encoding and/or commas instead of dots in time def.